# why the jdk native refactor get class from heap

Tags: java, c++, jvm

I am reading the [jdk 19](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/)(support the m1 chip when compile) source code, in the refactor source code in `reflection.cpp`, the function look like this:

```
oop Reflection::invoke_method(oop method_mirror, Handle receiver, objArrayHandle args, TRAPS) {
  oop mirror             = java_lang_reflect_Method::clazz(method_mirror);
  int slot               = java_lang_reflect_Method::slot(method_mirror);
  bool override          = java_lang_reflect_Method::override(method_mirror) != 0;
}
```

when I tracing this clazz function `java_lang_reflect_Method::clazz`:

```
oop java_lang_reflect_Method::clazz(oop reflect) {
  return reflect->obj_field(_clazz_offset);
}
```

the `obj_field` function get the oop data from heap. This makes me a little confusing, the heap store the all object instance, why the reflection get data from heap? I think it will get the metadata from Method Area because in there store the class metadata, using the metadata, could construct the class info. the `obj_field` look like this:

```
inline oop  oopDesc::obj_field(int offset) const                    { return HeapAccess<>::oop_load_at(as_oop(), offset);  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reads the `clazz` field of a [`java.lang.reflect.Method`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/reflect/Method.java#L71) object.

`java.lang.reflect.Method` is a regular Java class (with some support from native helpers). Why do you expect it not to be stored on the heap?

---

Note that [`java.lang.reflect.Method`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/reflect/Method.java#L69) is not the same as a hotspot-internal C++ [`class Method`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/oops/method.hpp#L69).

The [`class Method`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/oops/method.hpp#L69) is an implementation detail of the hotspot JVM engine and instances of this internal C++ class are never stored on the heap.